# mysql query taking 46 seconds - needs to be more efficient

Tags: mysql

I have arrived at a query that gives me what I want but it is not efficient and takes over 45 seconds to execute. How can I modify to make this quicker?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT email, 
                    title, 
                    first_name, 
                    last_name, 
                    'chauntry' AS source, 
                    post_code  AS postcode 
    FROM   chauntry 
    WHERE  mailing_indicator = 1) AS x 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT email, 
                     Avg(amount_paid)                AS avg_paid, 
                     Count(*)                        AS no_times_booked, 
                     Count(DISTINCT( Month(added) )) AS unique_months 
              FROM   chauntry 
              WHERE  added >= Now() - INTERVAL 1 year 
              GROUP  BY email) AS y 
          ON x.email = y.email
```

here are the data fields
[image]

here are the column headings I am after
[image]

Comment: What's the execution plan for the query?  Any indexes on the tables?

Comment: No indexes - Both queries are on the same table. I needed to get all the contacts who have opted to a newsletter but join all their booking history for the entire year regardless of whether they had opted in or not if that's makes sense.

Comment: What's the execution plan?

Comment: Hi bluefeet, im out of my depth here so apologies - not sure about the execution plan - any pointers?

Comment: [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Comment: Is there anything you can see on my query that would slow it down this much? is there a more efficient way to do this query?

Comment: You can try indexing email...

Comment: Try adding a group by at the end of the query?

Comment: In this case, it would make more sense to show us sample data and expected result.

Comment: I have edited the question and added some column headings to give an idea

Answer (score 0):

To help your performance, you really need indexes.  Since you are in essence running two different queries, I would have the following indexes on your CHAUNTRY table

First... by having the mailing_indicator first, you are jumping directly to those, then getting email too which is a basis for the join after.  You could actually extend the index to include title, first, last, post_code to be a covering index, but that might be overkill.

```
( mailing_indicator, email )
```

Your LEFT JOIN query, it appears you want the count, avg, etc regardless of the mailing_indicator status.  To help optimize this, I would have an index on

```
( added, email, amount_paid )
```

This WOULD be a covering index so the engine does not need to go to the raw data pages to query the data, but gets them directly from the index.

One additional note about your count of distinct months.  You MIGHT be missing a count entry.  Consider the middle of the month, such as now Jan 28.

if you have entries for Jan 29, 2014 and Jan 27, 2015, they will fall into the same distinct month count basis as 1 and not 2 representing two different months as they span month AND year.  You might want to change that to

```
DATE_FORMAT(added, '%M %Y') as unique_months_yrs
```

[Syntax to create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

```
CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_type]

Create index Chauntry_MailInd_EMail on Chauntry ( mailing_indicator, email );
Create index Chauntry_Add_Email_Paid on Chauntry  ( added, email, amount_paid );
```

Comment: I have tried indexing as you suggest but not getting any joy, for example: ALTER TABLE `chauntry` 
  ADD INDEX(`mailing_indicator`, `email`);  - is this the correct way?

Comment: @Jeff, revised answer... your syntax appears valid, however if having problems with that, you could go create index syntax as I've revised answer here.

Answer (score 0):

DRapp, appreciate the detailed feedback - spot on about the date being an oversight.

Are we talking about something like the below to speed up my query? I cant find much info about creating a covering index and the source of the below one was questionable.

```
ALTER TABLE `chauntry` 
  ADD INDEX(`mailing_indicator`, `email`); 

ALTER TABLE `chauntry` 
  ADD INDEX covering_index (`added`, `email`, `amount_paid`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use SELECT DISTINCT in the first subquery, and GROUP BY in the second subquery.
Which has the same effect.

Subqueries in a from clause are often redundant, they produce derived tables which aren't indexed. When you run explain over the query you'll see 4 tabels in the execution plan. This can be rewritten to a query without subqueries:

```
SELECT x.email, 
    x.title, 
    x.first_name, 
    x.last_name, 
    'chauntry' AS source, 
    post_code  AS postcode,
    Avg(y.amount_paid) AS avg_paid, 
    Count(y.email) AS no_times_booked, 
    Count(DISTINCT( Month(y.added) )) AS unique_months
FROM
    chauntry x
LEFT JOIN
    chaunrty y
    ON x.email = y.email AND y.added >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY x.email
```

However your model isn't properly normalized, you should have two tables, one with the account data, and one with the payments