# mysql index guidance needed - group by sub query super slow

Tags: mysql

Quick overview, I have worked out a mysql query but need to optimize the performance.

My original post was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197543/mysql-query-taking-46-seconds-needs-to-be-more-efficient) but its gone cold and im getting desperate to elaborate on some of the suggestions which I tried to implement. So its not a dupe post but it is related.

Here is the query that takes 45 seconds plus, the group by on the second sub query really slows things down.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT email,
       title,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       'chauntry' AS source,
    post_code AS postcode
FROM chauntry
WHERE mailing_indicator = 1
) AS x
JOIN
(
SELECT email, 
           Avg(amount_paid)                AS avg_paid, 
           Count(*)                        AS no_times_booked, 
           Count(DISTINCT( Date_format(added, '%M %Y') )) AS unique_months 
    FROM   chauntry 
    WHERE  added >= Now() - INTERVAL 1 year 
    GROUP  BY email
) AS y
ON x.email = y.email
```

Based on the index suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197543/mysql-query-taking-46-seconds-needs-to-be-more-efficient) I looked around for a few examples of indexing and came up with the below

```
ALTER TABLE `chauntry` 
  ADD INDEX(`mailing_indicator`, `email`); 

ALTER TABLE `chauntry` 
  ADD INDEX covering_index (`added`, `email`, `amount_paid`);
```

This makes no difference to the query time and im not sure if what im doing is even close as up until now I have had no need to use indexing.

suggestions welcome on how to index my table correctly or how to modify the query.

Comment: can you add the `explain` output of this query ?

Comment: Sure - the data is all from the same table. First query grabs all the contacts who have opted in (mailing indicator = 1). The second query gets some numbers on their purchase history for the last year regardless of whether they opted in or not (they can opt in one time but not he next) as long as they opted in once at some point is all we care about.

Comment: No not an explanation to what you are doing. I meant: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: How many records are there in each sub query? As they are sub queries the indexes will not help with joining them together.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiousity, does this query do what you want?

```
SELECT email, title, first_name, last_name, 'chauntry' AS source,
       post_code AS postcode,
       Avg(amount_paid)                AS avg_paid, 
       Count(*)                        AS no_times_booked, 
       Count(DISTINCT( Date_format(added, '%M %Y') )) AS unique_months 
FROM   chauntry 
WHERE  added >= Now() - INTERVAL 1 year 
GROUP  BY email, title, first_name, last_name, post_code
HAVING SUM(mailing_indicator = 1) > 0;
```

It would seem to follow the same logic as your query, except that the mailing indicator would need to have been set in the past year.

Comment: This looks like the best answer. What was the syntax error ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer . . . If I had to guess, there was a missing comma after `postcode` when Jeff made that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `JOIN` on subselects to same table?
I would try this:

```
SELECT email,
           title,
           first_name,
           last_name,
           'chauntry' AS source,
           post_code AS postcode
           Avg(amount_paid)                               AS avg_paid, 
           Count(*)                                       AS no_times_booked, 
           Count(DISTINCT( Date_format(added, '%M %Y') )) AS unique_months
FROM chauntry
WHERE
    mailing_indicator = 1 and
    added >= Now() - INTERVAL 1 year
GROUP BY email
```

Also I don't think you need any index with query like this, maybe on `added` and `email`, but you already added them.

Comment: I have the added complication that I need the booking history for all their transactions regardless of whether they opted in (sometimes they with opt in via mailing indicator = 1 and sometimes they don't). I only need to know they opted in once.

Comment: In that case you're doing business logic in your SQL. Why not somehow divide this into 2 queries maybe? 46 seconds is pretty long...
Or remove `WHERE mailing_indicator = 1 and` and select that field into data returned and dod the business logic from code, not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Minor play.

The average of the amount_paid is the biggest problem. If you are prepared to put up with the possibility of an inaccuracy for this figure then you could maybe average the distinct values of the amount_paid field. This WILL give the wrong value under certain circumstances (ie, if you had 100 bookings, 99 at $1 and 1 at $100 the average would be given as $50.50 rather than $1.99), but if the amount paid is never repeated then this may be acceptable.

Otherwise you can probably use a join of the table against itself. To get the no_times_booked you can count the DISTINCT unique identifiers of the table (I have assumed id here).

```
SELECT  c1.email,
        c1.title,
        c1.first_name,
        c1.last_name,
        'chauntry'                      AS source,
        c1.post_code                    AS postcode
        Avg(DISTINCT c2.amount_paid)    AS avg_paid, 
        Count(DISTINCT c2.id)           AS no_times_booked, 
        Count(DISTINCT( Date_format(c2.added, '%M %Y') )) AS unique_months 
FROM chauntry c1
INNER JOIN chauntry c2
ON c1.email = c2.email
WHERE c1.mailing_indicator = 1
AND c2.added >= Now() - INTERVAL 1 year 
GROUP BY c1.email,
        c1.title,
        c1.first_name,
        c1.last_name,
        source,
        c1.post_code
```